# Daisy Chain on the AD7284 not working

Tags: pcb-design, bms

We are building a battery management system with BMS IC [AD7284](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7284.pdf). Communication to the first device is done via SPI. Following devices can be addressed with a proprietary daisy chain protocol (differential current-signal). Addressing the master only works fine. However, addressing slaves via daisy chain (as detailed on p. 32) yields no response on SPI.

Therefore, we measure the voltage on the daisy chain wires differentially. When the slave is connected (pic#2) there is an extra pulse. It follows the burst which relates to the "Init Daisy chain" command via SPI. Other SPI messages which e.g. request register values from the slave, aren't followed by such a pulse. As it only appears with a connected slave, we suspect it to be a response from the slave. Next, we try to get a response to other SPI commands.

**Things we tried:**

- Send a SPI message telling the slave to output daisy chain logic levels on GPIO pins (p. 35)

  - -> White noise is measured on the pins before and after sending the command. On master, logic levels are displayed instead.
- Switch 50 for 200 ohms as terminating resistors (p. 48)

  - -> Different signal noise ratio on daisy chain.
- Add capacitor in series to Daisy Chain. It is depicted on page ?. Contrary, in the text, it is stated that if one uses a transformer (as we do), there is no need for it.

  - -> No difference measured.
- Remove transformer and use capacitor instead (fig. 43).

  - -> No signal at all on the daisy chain.
- We applied the minimum delays for sending SPI: 200ns after message (p. 7), 50us after switch R/W bit (p. 29), 25us * nSlaves after init daisy chain (p. 38).
- And in the next step a little more than minimum. No difference.

Unfortunately, the chip is not recommended for new designs. So mailing Analog for support didn't help. Our [post](https://ez.analog.com/power/battery-management-system/f/qa/559022/daisychain-communication-with-the-ad7284) on their forum didn't gather any attention.

Any ideas for what to try next, samples of working daisy chain on this chip, nudges in a new direction etc. are appreciated.

[image: No Slave connected]
#1 No Slave connected.

[image: Slave connected]
#2 Slave connected. Same 2 pulses plus another one.

[image: Schematic of Daisy chain circuit]
Schematic of Daisy chain circuit.

Comment: I see nothing in the datasheet referring to series capacitors, except for using ones shunted by diodes (which you don't have, and which would be important) at disconnect points. Can you provide a reference for this capacitor connection?

Comment: Does the circuit work if you *don't* try to provide hot plug capability?

Comment: How is the control register 2 configured in a slave? Who can configure it if there is no MCU?

Comment: @Hearth In the beginning, we had operated the transformers without capacitors in series. We then added the capacitors because of figure 45.

So we haven't used the hot plug capabilty yet. Firstly we tried the transformer schematic (fig. 45) and after this the direct connection without transformer and with board-to-board connection (fig. 40).

Comment: @Jens We have not found any other possibility except the configuration via the daisy chain.

Comment: The preamble in the answer of the slave looks inverted. Is the polarity accidentially swapped somewhere? The answer could just be a CRC error message.

Comment: @Jens Indeed, D_DWN and NOT(D_DWN) are accidently swapped on the slave pcb. We will test now if it works, when we correct that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preamble in the answer of the slave looks inverted. The polarity of the two communication lines is accidentially swapped somewhere. The answer probably is just a CRC error report message.

If the D_DWN and NOT(D_DWN) pins are connected correctly, the slave too responds on SPI. On the daisy chain, there is no response to "Init daisy chain" anymore. Instead, the intended messages are responded.[image]